# Extract and count value position from specified Descendant node

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

From this XHTML source:

```
<div class = "page">  
<h1>UNIQUE NAME</h1>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>DATA TO EXTRACT 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td />
        <td />
        <td />
        <td />
        <td />
        <td>DATA TO EXTRACT 2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 etc...
```

There are multiple instances of UNIQUE NAME with a similar set of child elements.

I need to locate the UNIQUE NAME element and extract all values (DATA TO EXTRACT) within each of the child element  tags. In addition, I need to keep a count of where each value is located. For example DATA TO EXTRACT 1 would be at tr 1, td 1. DATA TO EXTRACT 2 would be at tr 2, td 6.

I am new to linq to xml and I was wondering whether someone could point me in the right direction with regards to a strategy. I have managed to figure out how to get to the UNIQUE name element with the following code:

```
var choice1 = (from category in _data.Descendants("div")
                       where category.Element("h1").Value == "UNIQUE NAME"
                       select category).DescendantNodes();
```

This returns a set of the values, which I'm sure I could loop through but I'm sure there must be a more elegant way of achieving this goal.

Many thanks!

Comment: I have the feeling that Linq is not the right tool for this job or at least not the best. Perhaps an HTML parser like HTMLAgilityPack is best suited for this(?)

Comment: Thanks Icarus, I'll check this out for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s one way of doing it using LINQ:

```
var choice1 =
    from category in _data.Descendants("div")
    where category.Element("h1").Value == "UNIQUE NAME"
    from row in category.Descendants("tr").Select((element, index) => new { element, index })
    from col in row.element.Elements("td").Select((element, index) => new { element, index })
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(col.element.Value)
    select new
    {
        RowIndex = row.index + 1,   // one-based index
        ColIndex = col.index + 1,
        Value = col.element.Value,
    };
```

An example of how to use your results:

```
foreach (var v in choice1)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
        "RowIndex = {0}, ColIndex = {1}, Value = \"{2}\".",
        v.RowIndex, v.ColIndex, v.Value));
```

…which would output:

```
RowIndex = 1, ColIndex = 1, Value = "DATA TO EXTRACT 1".
RowIndex = 2, ColIndex = 6, Value = "DATA TO EXTRACT 2".
```